# Is there a way to increase the log size in docker when building a container?

Tags: docker

In the output when building, I am getting this message:

`[output clipped, log limit 1MiB reached]`

from the command

`docker build --progress plain .`

The current workaround I have is to pipe larger sections of the RUN command in the dockerfile to /dev/null i.e.

```
RUN \
 echo "**** install packages ****" && \
 apt-get update && \
 apt-get install -y libcairo2-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libpng-dev libtool-bin libossp-uuid-dev wget maven default-jdk > /dev/null
```

Comment: You can set a bigger logsize with `--driver-opt env.BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SIZE=10485760` (i.e 10MiB)

Comment: could also use quite flag `-qq`, combining `-yqq`

Comment: To add a little clarity, I'm looking to show the log output to see where the build is failing. -qq or sending to /dev/null works just fine, but I can't see the output I'm looking for when troubleshooting.

`--driver-opt` isn't an available flag.
```
docker build --driver-opt env.BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SIZE=10485760 .
unknown flag: --driver-opt
See 'docker build --help'.
```

I'm assuming that the --driver-opt flag was taken from buildx, but that doesn't seem to be an option for buildx unless you enable experimental mode. -- testing experimental mode with buildx now.

Comment: I was able to get around this issue by creating a builder with `docker buildx create --driver-opt env.BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SIZE=50000000` and then using the builder with `docker buildx build`, but have not been able to fix the issue when using the default builder and `docker build`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With the key link provided by @Luke Deluccia, this is what worked for me.

```
docker buildx create --use --name larger_log --driver-opt env.BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SIZE=50000000
docker buildx build --progress plain .
```

This creates a buildx instance, and sets buildx to use the instance when building. This did not clip the logs during the build process.

Comment: Glad this worked for you as well. The only problem is that it does not use the default builder context, which many may want. If I find a solution for that, I'll post it here.

Comment: I get: `error: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to read dockerfile: open /tmp/buildkit-mount113931619/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 9):

The other solution is for `docker buildx`, but some might want a fix for `docker build` with `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`. The following works for me on `ubuntu18.04` and docker version `5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic`.

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/env.conf 
[Service]
Environment="BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SIZE=1073741824" # you might want to tweak this
Environment="BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SPEED=10240000"
```

Then:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker.service
```

Answer (score 9):

Was on WSL2 docker. The buildx solution somehow didn't work.

But disabling buildkit and piping the output into a file worked for me

So doing this in a bash shell worked for me:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
docker build --progress plain ./ > logoutput.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows 11, Docker Desktop, Docker version 20.10.17.

To turn off BUILDKIT, in the Docker Desktop settings, under "Docker Engine" on the left side, if there's a json block like:

```
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  }
```

change it to `false`. If the `features` block isn't there, it should be under the root `{`, add it with `"buildkit": false`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer to complete [@AlexanderSergeyev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2784509/alexander-sergeyev) answer's.

This was not working for me on Ubuntu 20.04 because `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d` folder does not exists.

Also, my Docker version is

```
Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289
```

I have to do this instead:

```sh
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service
```

Then under the `[Service]` tag, put those lines:

```sh
Environment="BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SIZE=1073741824"
Environment="BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SPEED=10240000"
```

And then restart docker daemon:

```sh
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker.service
```

Comment: You don't want to edit the `/wants/` files because those are symlinks, so you end up editing the main file. You could edit the main /etc/systemd/system/docker.service file. However, a re-install might then lose this, because it means you're patching the installed script.

Answer (score 1):

for windows:

in cmd run the command:

```
set DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
```

and restart docker desktop

Answer (score 1):

According to [the source](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/1754/files) it's possible to completely eliminate any limitations using `-1` value for both variables:

```
$ docker buildx create --bootstrap --use --name buildkit \
    --driver-opt env.BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SIZE=-1 \
    --driver-opt env.BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SPEED=-1
$ docker buildx build --progress plain .
```