# Docker Build throwing a error -"Docker output clipped, log limit 1MiB reached"

Tags: docker, logging, docker-image, docker-desktop, docker-build

While Building my docker Image in **Docker Desktop** for windows,after some sort of time It throwing a error:

> => => # [output clipped, log limit 1MiB reached]

I tired configuring the log file size in daemon file and restarted the docker service

```
 "log-driver": "json-file",
 "log-opts": 
{
"max-size": "10m",
 "max-file": "3"
}
```

But still I'm  getting the same error, Any one please advise me on this ?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Have you found a solution? @Nirmal

Comment: Same question was asked here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819424/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-log-size-in-docker-when-building-a-container

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to increase the log size in docker when building a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819424/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-log-size-in-docker-when-building-a-container)

Answer (score 8):

Per https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/ it suggests to:

> Restart Docker for the changes to take effect for newly created containers. Existing containers do not use the new logging configuration.

Unfortunatelly `docker build` doesn't support `--log-opt max-buffer-size=XXXm`, but [`buildx` does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819424/)

As "the last shoot", you can remove `--progress plain` if you don't acutally need it

Answer (score 2):

You can use below one-line command when you use buildx:

```
docker buildx build . --builder "$(docker buildx create --driver-opt env.BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SIZE=10000000 --driver-opt env.BUILDKIT_STEP_LOG_MAX_SPEED=10000000)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered that happened because buildkit is enabled. So I disabled buildkit and it works fine for me:

```
"features": {
    "buildkit": false
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if you use `--mount=type=cache` as that requires BuildKit to be enabled to function.

Comment: speed up the this search this file for win users
%USERPROFILE%/.docker

Comment: Buildkit does a lot more than truncate logs. To me, it is not acceptable to throw away the build speed gained by buildkit.